# "Evaluation of practical experience (=internship) and it's contribution"

Tags: english-to-japanese

> "Evaluation of practical experience (=internship) and it's contribution"

I would use something like this:

> 「実習【じっしゅう】評価【ひょうか】及び【および】その貢献【こうけん】」

I could be relatively satisfied (but just partly) with 実習【じっしゅう】 as for "practical experience" and 評価【ひょうか】 as for "evaluation", but I feel uncomfortable by using 貢献【こうけん】 as for "contribution". I haven't used 貢献【こうけん】 before and haven't used yet any other alternative meaning for the word "contribution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contribution can be translated either as 貢献(度) and 寄与【きよ】(度).

- 貢献: beneficial contribution from people (by money, labor, source code, etc)
- [寄与](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%AF%84%E4%B8%8E): contribution of various inanimate factors (e.g., price, demand, temperature, ...). (can be positive or negative)
- ～度: value, degree

If you are asking how much the "practical experience" has affected something, 寄与度 is probably the best choice.

I don't know the context, but "practical experience" can be translated [differently](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=practical%20experience&ref=sa). Please make sure 実習 is the right translation in the context in question.

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
Otherwise, as I stated in text, under the "practical experience" I mean internship. Hope 実習 is close by it's meaning...

Comment: @Fara Maybe you mean 研修?